# "...Повторяя свой круг" - так можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Варвары и вандалы, сарацины, позже норманны, а также пожары и
>   наводнения, землетрясения и моровые поветрия, – словом, все возможные
>   бедствия, **на протяжении нескольких столетий снова и снова повторяя
>   свой круг**, превратили величественную столицу в тёмный, грязный,
>   опасный и наводящий ужас город-призрак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, лучше просто "повторяя круг", то есть двигаясь по кругу.
Пример из Нацкорпуса:

Три вечных слова ― было, есть и будет―
Не замыкая, повторяют круг.

Н. В. Крандиевская. Эпитафия (1954)

Comment: Я думаю: может, лучше *круговорот*? Или не поможет?

Comment: Повторять круговорот - плеоназм (круговорот и есть повторяющийся процесс)

Comment: М. б., *снова и снова описывая свой круг*? Всяк плохо...

Comment: А по-моему, неплохо: "снова и снова описывая свой круг".

Answer (score 3):

*Варвары и вандалы, сарацины, позже норманны, а также пожары...*
Ой, а пожары — это кто? Честное слово, при первом прочтении возникает такой вопрос. Поэтому я бы поменяла *пожары* и *наводнения* местами.
А "круг" бы оформила, обозначив период времени — "из века в век" (по аналогии с "из года в год"), а накопленные проблемы — словом "жестокий":

*Варвары и вандалы, сарацины, позже норманны, а также наводнения и пожары, землетрясения и моровые поветрия, – словом, все возможные бедствия, **из века в век повторяя жестокий круг**, превратили...*

Comment: Проголосовал за, так как фраза "зазвучала", но все-таки не могу не заметить: есть небольшая смысловая разница между "на протяжении нескольких столетий" (огранченный срок) и "из века в век" (скорее всего, означает "всегда")

Comment: Конечно, разница есть! Зато красиво. Но и понятно же, что не до бесконечности. Когда-то ведь эти напасти закончатся (только вот когда и чем?).

Answer (score 1):

повторяя (обычный) круг своих бесчинств

Comment: Негодяй... Помоги деушке-стаушке книжку выправить...

Answer (score 1):

Варвары и вандалы, сарацины, позже норманны, а также пожары и наводнения, землетрясения и моровые поветрия, – словом, все возможные бедствия, **на протяжении нескольких столетий повторяясь вновь и вновь,** превратили величественную столицу в тёмный, грязный, опасный и наводящий ужас город-призрак.

Повторяя свой круг  – местоимение вроде бы лишнее, повторяя круг – очень бедно, хотелось бы какое-нибудь подходящее определение. Что-то вроде "зловещий круг", только чтобы не так страшно.